# Can you replicate a wallet somewhere else

Tags: wallet

If I used my 12 seed words in another wallet provider that used the 12 word backup protocal, whether hard hot or mobile, would that then replicate my wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the same seed phrase on a different device/in different software will create another instance of the same wallet (assuming both wallets are following the same derivation path, etc).

This is a nice feature of BIP32 hierarchical deterministic wallets: you are not necessarily tied to the wallet software that you used to create the wallet in the first place. If that wallet software stops being developed for whatever reason, you can recreate your wallet using some other software/hardware.